# How to disable BottomNavigationView click and Touch?

Tags: android, behavior, bottomnavigationview

i want to implement behavior on certain condition the **bottom view** is unable to click, i want to make if bottom view item being click it does not navigate to that item but still stay at the current item

[image: this is my bottom view layout]

Comment: add your code here

Comment: i just want to impliment, but do not know how,

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can disable menu items if you want to disable bottom navigation view

```
private void enableBottomBar(boolean enable){
    for (int i = 0; i < mBottomMenu.getMenu().size(); i++) {
        mBottomMenu.getMenu().getItem(i).setEnabled(enable);
    }
}
```

Comment: mBottomMenu.menu.iterator().forEach { it.isEnabled = enable }

Comment: How can I hide a particular tab for eg) say the home tab needs to be hidden in the landscape mode.

Answer (score 12):

Kotlin style one-liner:

```
bottom_navigation.menu.forEach { it.isEnabled = false }
```

Comment: Kotlin one-liner FTW!

Answer (score 2):

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:contextClickable="false"/>
```

Try this code.it Disables the click.

Dynamicaly using Java pr Kotlin you can disable click.

```
    bottomView.setEnabled(false); 
    bottomView.setFocusable(false); 
    bottomView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    bottomView.setClickable(false); 
    bottomView.setContextClickable(false);
    bottomView.setOnClickListener(null);
```

setting onClick Listener to Null helps to Disable click events

```
bottomView.menu.forEach { it.isEnabled = false }
```

Comment: i still can click and choose the item

Comment: bottomView.setOnClickListener(null); try this.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the touch listeners of its subviews. Example using android-ktx:

```
bottomNav.children.forEach {
   (it as? ViewGroup)?.children?.forEach {
       it.setOnTouchListener { _, _ -> true } // or null to enable touch again
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomBottomNavigationView extends BottomNavigationView {

    ...

    @Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        super.setEnabled(enabled);
        ViewGroup menuView = (ViewGroup) getChildAt(0);
        if (menuView != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                menuView.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(enabled);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
bottomNavigation.menu.iterator().forEach { it.isEnabled = !error }
```